# Animating a table view section header

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created this table view section header. It is basically a `UIView` container where I wrapped all elements that will go on that section header.

This container view is returned by

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and everything is working fine.

Now I want the header to appear in fade in, as the table appears. So, I initially declare `alpha = 0` for the container and then do this on `viewDidAppear:` (ah, this table is inside a view controller that is appearing).

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
         animations:^{
             [self.tableHeader setAlpha:1.0f];
     }];

}
```

Nothing happens and the header continues to be invisible.

I have tried to add:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates]; //and
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
```

before and after the mentioned animation, without success.

It appears to me that the table header is not updating and continues to be invisible.

Comment: Does changing alpha without the animation work?

Comment: Maybe post where you defined the alpha=0.0 initially. This may be overriding the animation.

Comment: When are you creating `self.tableHeader` and are you returning it in the `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` method?

Comment: yes, as I said in the 3rd line of this post... :D

Comment: @PengOne the declaration was inside tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:

Comment: @PengOne you are right! DUUUUHH! I have declared alpha inside tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:, so, everytime the table is drawn alpha will be 0. But now I have another problem. How do animate it back to 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, put a `NSLog` on both `viewDidAppear` and `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`

You gonna see that the `viewDidAppear` executes first, once tableView has an asynchronous loading and you don't know when will call the `viewForHeaderInSection`.

One workaround is the following:

```
-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    _tableHeader = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
    _tableHeader.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    _tableHeader.alpha = 0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 animations:^{
                     [_tableHeader setAlpha:1.0f];
                 }];

    return _tableHeader;

}
```

Just call the animation when the table will return the viewHeader.

Comment: that's it. Perfect. I thought the view was not visible before it was returned on the method, but it is. Thanks!